# Not emitting/receiving events with socket.io and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I have this very  basic socket.io setup that you have probably seen a thousand times already.

Please not that here that the files are served via apache.

**server** (app.js)

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 
    socket.emit('server ready', {msg: 'hi'}) ;

    socket.on('random event', function(data) {
        console.log('received');
    })
});
```

and **client**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080/projectname/server/');

    socket.on('server ready', function(data){ 
        console.log('server ready!'); 
    });

    socket.emit('random event', {hurr: 'durr'});
});
```

However, the only output I get is

```
 debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"server ready","args":[{"msg":"hi"}]}
```

in the node console and nothing in the client console. Which is wrong.

I have tried the basic example from the socket.io website and it shows exactly the same behaviour. It logs the emitted data in the node console but nothing else seems to happen.

Edit: Upon further investigation, visiting the site  in Firefox creates a different output in the node console:

```
info  - handshake authorized 178702677759276313
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/178702677759276313?t=1339080239192
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 1::
   debug - set close timeout for client 178702677759276313
   debug - xhr-polling received data packet �17�1::/stock/server/�66�5::/stock/server/:{"name":"random event","args":[{"hurr":"durr"}]}
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/178702677759276313?t=1339080239263
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 5:::{"name":"server ready","args":[{"msg":"hi"}]}
```

This looks like the data emitted fromt he client actually reached the server. However, it didnt seem to solve the actual problem: the console.log lines and both the client and the server side arent executed. **This output is from Firefox 5.0.1** where it seems to fall back to xhr.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why `http://127.0.0.1:8080/projectname/server/` and not `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` or simply `io.connect()` ?

Comment: i cant quite tell, this is more a result of trial and error. this is where the server app.js is. everything else throws a clientside 404 on socket.io.js. maybe it is because I have an apache webserver running on localhost at the same time.

Comment: Are you proxy-ing to Node through Apache or what exactly?

Comment: not knowingly. i am new to these things. the files are served with apache via some standard port (80 i assume). the client connects to socket.io via port 8080 how you can see.

Comment: Sounds like you can drop `projectname/server` and just connect to `127.0.0.1:8080`. If the client is connecting direct to your node app on port 8080, the location where your app.js is doesn't matter.. it lives at `8080`.

Which version of Firefox did you use in that second log? Socket.io fell back to xhr polling.. it's not even running web sockets.

Comment: i cannot drop the path, else I get a 404 error on getting the client socket.io.js. the version was 5.0.1 (i usually dont use ff). updating now.

Comment: yes, the different output just comes from firefox being outdated. with the most recent version, the output is the same than with chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `projectname` is `stock`, then that's your problem. Socket.IO is thinking you're using a [namespace](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io#restricting-yourself-to-a-namespace). You can see this in the `xhr-polling received data packet` log line. `console.log` is never called since you're not listening on that namespace on the server side.

You should get rid of `/projectname/server` from your client connect address and reference the client side library properly so you don't get a 404. Whether that's an Apache proxy issue or fixing the `script src` in your header depends on your current setup. I can't tell from the code you've provided.

PS: Socket.io should serve the client library at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`, but you might run into a cross-domain origin policy issue by referencing that asset from a document served by your apache server at port 80. Quick fix could be to serve the client lib from your apache server, which is in the `socket.io-client` module `dist` folder.

Comment: Thank you! regarding your PS, this is what I just did.